# Get the fields and values from a Spark RDD

Tags: json, apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark RDD(org.apache.spark.rdd) made from a JSON string that looks like this :

```
{"id":1 , "text":"sample1"}
```

I am using spray JSON in my application and I need to extract the keys into a `JsArray (keys_jsArray)` - (contains id, text).

Also the values to be extracted into another `JsArray`. - (contains 1, sample1)

I am stuck in parsing the RDD to extract the keys and values so that I can form two JsArrays.